# How to override templates per Entity in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I would like to override a CRUD list template on a per Admin / entity basis.

Assume I have an Admin class called `MyAdminClass`. I want to override the CRUD list template for *that class*, but not the whole application by adding templates to `app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/Views/CRUD`. How can I achieve this?

Also, how would I override a group of templates rather than just one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Form [the documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html#configuring-templates):

> If you wish, you can specify custom templates on a per Admin mapping basis. Internally, the CRUDController fetches this information from the Admin class instance, so you can specify the templates to use in the Admin service definition:
>
> XML:
>
> ```
> <service id="sonata.admin.post" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Admin\PostAdmin">
>     <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="Content" label="Post"/>
>     <argument />
>     <argument>Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Post</argument>
>     <argument />
>     <call method="setTemplate">
>         <argument>edit</argument>
>         <argument>AcmeDemoBundle:PostAdmin:edit.html.twig</argument>
>     </call>
> </service>
> ```
>
> Yaml:
>
> ```
> services:
>     sonata.admin.post:
>         class: Acme\DemoBundle\Admin\PostAdmin
>         tags:
>             - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Post" }
>         arguments:
>             - ~
>             - Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Post
>             - ~
>         calls:
>             - [ setTemplate, [edit, AcmeDemoBundle:PostAdmin:edit.html.twig]]
> ```

An example of using `setTemplates`:

XML:

```
<service id="sonata.admin.post" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Admin\PostAdmin">
    <!-- ... -->

    <call method="setTemplates">
        <argument type="collection">
            <argument key="edit">
                AcmeDemoBundle:PostAdmin:edit.html.twig
            </argument>
            <argument key="list">
                AcmeDemoBundle:PostAdmin:list.html.twig
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </call>
</service>
```

Yaml:

```
services:
    sonata.admin.post:
        # ...

        calls:
            - [setTemplates, [{edit: AcmeDemoBundle:PostAdmin:edit.html.twig, list: AcmeDemoBundle:PostAdmin:list.html.twig }]]
```

Comment: thanks, I also just found this (d'oh). What do you use to alert you to new Symfony questions on SO?

Comment: a setTemplates (plural) example would also be useful

Comment: @codecowboy I've added a `setTemplates` example. Btw, can you please accept this answer if it solves your problem? For you other question: I use a combination of Favourite and Ignored tags and just visit SO often :)

Comment: thanks. yaml version needs to be setTemplates too ;)

Comment: How can I break this line `- [setTemplates, [{edit: AcmeDemoBundle:PostAdmin:edit.html.twig, list: AcmeDemoBundle:PostAdmin:list.html.twig }]]` up in multiple lines, because I don't want like 5 templates next to each other in one line

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I tried with setTemplates and setTemplate but none of that works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674827/settemplate-in-services-yaml-doesnt-work-with-my-own-template