# SetTemplate in services.yaml doesn't work with my own template

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin, sonata

I have a Sonata Admin and I wanna replace his template with another one, but doesn't work, currently my app is running in Symfony 4.3 and the folder structure changes with symfony version and I don't know if my error is in that place.

```
admin.expediente_compra:
    class: App\Admin\ExpedienteCompraAdmin
    arguments: [~, App\Entity\ExpedienteCompra, App\Controller\ExpedienteCompraAdminController]
    calls:
        - [setTemplate, ['edit', 'ExpedienteCompra/edit.html.twig']]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: ExpedienteCompra }
    public: true
```

My template is located in:

```
templates/ExpedienteCompra/edit.html.twig
```

Inside Symfony Profiler shows

[image: Rendered Templates]

Comment: Your code should work, with not working you mean you are not seeing your template? What is in your template and are you seeing the default one?

Comment: but doesn't work, I recently update sonata-admin but nothing happened. I put the image with Symfony Profiler

Comment: I follow each step in this tutorial https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/templates.html#configuring-templates but nothing happened

Comment: I could solve this problem, adding in the service another parameter: `autoconfigure: false` , without this it doesn't call any function inside label: `calls`

Comment: did you try to clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, I cleared cache, but the functions inside block calls in services.yaml never is called. But Works when I add @required annotation on my own function that call setTemplate